# The most efficient way to filter the radius over given coordinates

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Assume we have the following coordinates:

```
coord = Table[{i, j}, {j, 1.0, -1.0, -0.1}, {i, -1.0, 1.0, 0.1}]
```

What is the most efficient way to calculate the radius `r`. i.e. `r = sqrt(i^2+j^2)` and **set `r` to `0` for all `r` whose value is greater than 1**.

So basically it will get a list like `{0,0,0,0,0.989,0.979...0,0,0}`.

I already have my own solution, which is not elegant I think. And I hope the algorithm could be as fast as possible. So I would like to hear more sophisticated ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the distances, you can use [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total):

```
coord = Table[{i, j}, {j, 1.0, -1.0, -0.1}, {i, -1.0, 1.0, 0.1}];
d = Sqrt @ Total[coord^2, {3}];
```

*(since `coord` has dimensions $21 \times 21 \times 2$, the second argument of [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total) is `{3}`)*. Then, one idea is to use [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip):

```
res = Clip[d, {0, 1}, {1, 0}]
```

> {{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
>     0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.984886, 0.948683, 
>     0.921954, 0.905539, 0.9, 0.905539, 0.921954, 0.948683, 0.984886, 0.,
>      0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.943398, 0.894427, 
>     0.8544, 0.824621, 0.806226, 0.8, 0.806226, 0.824621, 0.8544, 
>     0.894427, 0.943398, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0.989949, 
>     0.921954, 0.860233, 0.806226, 0.761577, 0.728011, 0.707107, 0.7, 
>     0.707107, 0.728011, 0.761577, 0.806226, 0.860233, 0.921954, 
>     0.989949, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1., 0.921954, 0.848528, 0.781025, 
>     0.72111, 0.67082, 0.632456, 0.608276, 0.6, 0.608276, 0.632456, 
>     0.67082, 0.72111, 0.781025, 0.848528, 0.921954, 1., 0., 0.}, {0., 
>     0., 0.943398, 0.860233, 0.781025, 0.707107, 0.640312, 0.583095, 
>     0.538516, 0.509902, 0.5, 0.509902, 0.538516, 0.583095, 0.640312, 
>     0.707107, 0.781025, 0.860233, 0.943398, 0., 0.}, {0., 0.984886, 
>     0.894427, 0.806226, 0.72111, 0.640312, 0.565685, 0.5, 0.447214, 
>     0.412311, 0.4, 0.412311, 0.447214, 0.5, 0.565685, 0.640312, 0.72111,
>      0.806226, 0.894427, 0.984886, 0.}, {0., 0.948683, 0.8544, 0.761577,
>      0.67082, 0.583095, 0.5, 0.424264, 0.360555, 0.316228, 0.3, 
>     0.316228, 0.360555, 0.424264, 0.5, 0.583095, 0.67082, 0.761577, 
>     0.8544, 0.948683, 0.}, {0., 0.921954, 0.824621, 0.728011, 0.632456, 
>     0.538516, 0.447214, 0.360555, 0.282843, 0.223607, 0.2, 0.223607, 
>     0.282843, 0.360555, 0.447214, 0.538516, 0.632456, 0.728011, 
>     0.824621, 0.921954, 0.}, {0., 0.905539, 0.806226, 0.707107, 
>     0.608276, 0.509902, 0.412311, 0.316228, 0.223607, 0.141421, 0.1, 
>     0.141421, 0.223607, 0.316228, 0.412311, 0.509902, 0.608276, 
>     0.707107, 0.806226, 0.905539, 0.}, {1., 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 
>     0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9,
>      1.}, {0., 0.905539, 0.806226, 0.707107, 0.608276, 0.509902, 
>     0.412311, 0.316228, 0.223607, 0.141421, 0.1, 0.141421, 0.223607, 
>     0.316228, 0.412311, 0.509902, 0.608276, 0.707107, 0.806226, 
>     0.905539, 0.}, {0., 0.921954, 0.824621, 0.728011, 0.632456, 
>     0.538516, 0.447214, 0.360555, 0.282843, 0.223607, 0.2, 0.223607, 
>     0.282843, 0.360555, 0.447214, 0.538516, 0.632456, 0.728011, 
>     0.824621, 0.921954, 0.}, {0., 0.948683, 0.8544, 0.761577, 0.67082, 
>     0.583095, 0.5, 0.424264, 0.360555, 0.316228, 0.3, 0.316228, 
>     0.360555, 0.424264, 0.5, 0.583095, 0.67082, 0.761577, 0.8544, 
>     0.948683, 0.}, {0., 0.984886, 0.894427, 0.806226, 0.72111, 0.640312,
>      0.565685, 0.5, 0.447214, 0.412311, 0.4, 0.412311, 0.447214, 0.5, 
>     0.565685, 0.640312, 0.72111, 0.806226, 0.894427, 0.984886, 0.}, {0.,
>      0., 0.943398, 0.860233, 0.781025, 0.707107, 0.640312, 0.583095, 
>     0.538516, 0.509902, 0.5, 0.509902, 0.538516, 0.583095, 0.640312, 
>     0.707107, 0.781025, 0.860233, 0.943398, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
>     0.921954, 0.848528, 0.781025, 0.72111, 0.67082, 0.632456, 0.608276, 
>     0.6, 0.608276, 0.632456, 0.67082, 0.72111, 0.781025, 0.848528, 
>     0.921954, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0.989949, 0.921954, 0.860233, 
>     0.806226, 0.761577, 0.728011, 0.707107, 0.7, 0.707107, 0.728011, 
>     0.761577, 0.806226, 0.860233, 0.921954, 0.989949, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 
>     0., 0., 0., 1., 0.943398, 0.894427, 0.8544, 0.824621, 0.806226, 0.8,
>      0.806226, 0.824621, 0.8544, 0.894427, 0.943398, 0., 0., 0., 0., 
>     0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.984886, 0.948683, 0.921954, 
>     0.905539, 0.9, 0.905539, 0.921954, 0.948683, 0.984886, 0., 0., 0., 
>     0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 
>     0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}}

Since speed is a concern, here is the timing for a list of 10^7 points:

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[10, {10^7, 2}];
d = Sqrt @ Total[pts^2, {2}]; //AbsoluteTiming
Clip[d, {0, 1}, {1, 0}]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.334351, Null}
>
> {0.034603, Null}

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
 coord = Join @@Table[{i, j}, {j, 1.0, -1.0, -0.1}, {i, -1.0, 1.0, 0.1}]; 
   If[# > 1, 0, #] & /@ (Sqrt[#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2] & /@ coord)
```

Or you can do this.

```
coord = Join @@Table[{i, j, Sqrt[i^2 + j^2]}, {j, 1.0, -1.0, -0.1}, {i, -1.0, 1.0, 0.1}];
If[# > 1, 0, #] & /@ coord[[All, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this one is pretty neat.

Answer (score 2):

`Dot` is a bit faster than `Total`:

```
coord = Table[{i, j}, {j, 1.0, -1.0, -0.01}, {i, -1.0, 1.0, 0.01}];
a = Clip[Sqrt@Total[coord^2, {3}], {0, 1}, {1, 0}]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
b = Clip[Sqrt@Dot[coord^2, ConstantArray[1., 2]], {0., 1.}, {0., 0.}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a == b
```

> 0.00133
>
> 0.000428
>
> True

Note however that this is a dangerous operation to perform with finite precision as it is discontinuous. For example, compare this:

```
coord = Table[{i, j}, {j, 1.0, -1.0, -0.1}, {i, -1.0, 1.0, 0.1}];
coordI = Table[{i, j}, {j, 1, -1, -1/10}, {i, -1, 1, 1/10}];

b = Clip[Sqrt@Dot[coord^2, ConstantArray[1., 2]], {0., 1.}, {0., 0.}];
bI = Clip[Sqrt@Dot[coordI^2, ConstantArray[1, 2]], {0., 1.}, {0., 0.}];
b == bI
```

> False

So make sure that nobody's life depends on this code.

Comment: thanks for this enlightening idea!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This is another simple way:

```
transf[list_List] := 
  With[{n = list[[1]]^2 + list[[2]]^2}, If[n > 1, 0, Sqrt[n]]];
 Flatten@Map[transf, coord, {2}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.00214796, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.984886, 0.948683, 0.921954, 0.905539, 
>     0.9, 0.905539, 0.921954, 0.948683, 0.984886, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>      0, 0, 1., 0.943398, 0.894427, 0.8544, 0.824621, 0.806226, 0.8, 
>     0.806226, 0.824621, 0.8544, 0.894427, 0.943398, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>     0, 0, 0.989949, 0.921954, 0.860233, 0.806226, 0.761577, 0.728011, 
>     0.707107, 0.7, 0.707107, 0.728011, 0.761577, 0.806226, 0.860233, 
>     0.921954, 0.989949, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0.921954, 0.848528, 0.781025,
>      0.72111, 0.67082, 0.632456, 0.608276, 0.6, 0.608276, 0.632456, 
>     0.67082, 0.72111, 0.781025, 0.848528, 0.921954, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>     0.943398, 0.860233, 0.781025, 0.707107, 0.640312, 0.583095, 
>     0.538516, 0.509902, 0.5, 0.509902, 0.538516, 0.583095, 0.640312, 
>     0.707107, 0.781025, 0.860233, 0.943398, 0, 0, 0, 0.984886, 0.894427,
>      0.806226, 0.72111, 0.640312, 0.565685, 0.5, 0.447214, 0.412311, 
>     0.4, 0.412311, 0.447214, 0.5, 0.565685, 0.640312, 0.72111, 0.806226,
>      0.894427, 0.984886, 0, 0, 0.948683, 0.8544, 0.761577, 0.67082, 
>     0.583095, 0.5, 0.424264, 0.360555, 0.316228, 0.3, 0.316228, 
>     0.360555, 0.424264, 0.5, 0.583095, 0.67082, 0.761577, 0.8544, 
>     0.948683, 0, 0, 0.921954, 0.824621, 0.728011, 0.632456, 0.538516, 
>     0.447214, 0.360555, 0.282843, 0.223607, 0.2, 0.223607, 0.282843, 
>     0.360555, 0.447214, 0.538516, 0.632456, 0.728011, 0.824621, 
>     0.921954, 0, 0, 0.905539, 0.806226, 0.707107, 0.608276, 0.509902, 
>     0.412311, 0.316228, 0.223607, 0.141421, 0.1, 0.141421, 0.223607, 
>     0.316228, 0.412311, 0.509902, 0.608276, 0.707107, 0.806226, 
>     0.905539, 0, 1., 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0., 
>     0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1., 0, 0.905539, 
>     0.806226, 0.707107, 0.608276, 0.509902, 0.412311, 0.316228, 
>     0.223607, 0.141421, 0.1, 0.141421, 0.223607, 0.316228, 0.412311, 
>     0.509902, 0.608276, 0.707107, 0.806226, 0.905539, 0, 0, 0.921954, 
>     0.824621, 0.728011, 0.632456, 0.538516, 0.447214, 0.360555, 
>     0.282843, 0.223607, 0.2, 0.223607, 0.282843, 0.360555, 0.447214, 
>     0.538516, 0.632456, 0.728011, 0.824621, 0.921954, 0, 0, 0.948683, 
>     0.8544, 0.761577, 0.67082, 0.583095, 0.5, 0.424264, 0.360555, 
>     0.316228, 0.3, 0.316228, 0.360555, 0.424264, 0.5, 0.583095, 0.67082,
>      0.761577, 0.8544, 0.948683, 0, 0, 0.984886, 0.894427, 0.806226, 
>     0.72111, 0.640312, 0.565685, 0.5, 0.447214, 0.412311, 0.4, 0.412311,
>      0.447214, 0.5, 0.565685, 0.640312, 0.72111, 0.806226, 0.894427, 
>     0.984886, 0, 0, 0, 0.943398, 0.860233, 0.781025, 0.707107, 0.640312,
>      0.583095, 0.538516, 0.509902, 0.5, 0.509902, 0.538516, 0.583095, 
>     0.640312, 0.707107, 0.781025, 0.860233, 0.943398, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 
>     0.921954, 0.848528, 0.781025, 0.72111, 0.67082, 0.632456, 0.608276, 
>     0.6, 0.608276, 0.632456, 0.67082, 0.72111, 0.781025, 0.848528, 
>     0.921954, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.989949, 0.921954, 0.860233, 0.806226,
>      0.761577, 0.728011, 0.707107, 0.7, 0.707107, 0.728011, 0.761577, 
>     0.806226, 0.860233, 0.921954, 0.989949, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 
>     0.943398, 0.894427, 0.8544, 0.824621, 0.806226, 0.8, 0.806226, 
>     0.824621, 0.8544, 0.894427, 0.943398, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>      0, 0.984886, 0.948683, 0.921954, 0.905539, 0.9, 0.905539, 0.921954,
>      0.948683, 0.984886, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>      1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}